# como recoger variable desde mysql

Tags: php

quiero limitar la entrada de datos a bd cuando lavados sea igual o superior a maxlavados,
La consulta finaliza al sumar un solo lavado, en el debug la data que devuelve esta vacía y aun así sigue sumando uno. Como puedo limitarlo?
Gracias

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
include "db.php";
 
if($_POST['accept_request']) {
    $reg_id=$_POST['reg_id'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $status="true";
 
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM capsulas WHERE `username`='$username' and `status`='$status'");
    if ($q) {
            while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                if ($consulta['maxlavados'] >= $consulta['lavados']) {
                    $q1=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `capsulas` SET lavados = lavados+1 WHERE `reg_id`='$reg_id'");
                    echo "true";
                } else{
                    echo "false";
                }
            }
 
        else{
            echo "false";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Fallo la consulta";
    }
}
?
```

> 

eliminando el primer $q, sigue sumando solo uno, y me trae devuelta la array del data string y vacio el data,y me reenvia a una pagina undefined

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
include "db.php";

if($_POST['accept_request']) {
    $reg_id=$_POST['reg_id'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $date=date("d-m-y h:i:s");
    $status="true";


            while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                if ($consulta['maxlavados'] >= $consulta['lavados']) {
                    $q=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `capsulas` SET lavados = lavados+1, ultimo_lavado = '$date' WHERE `reg_id`='$reg_id'");
                    echo "true";
                } else{
                    echo "false";
                }
            }

        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Será que estas realizando el if con la primera query, la cual no vuelve a realizar nuevamente por ende nunca obtiene un valor actualizado.

la $q1 que hace el update no te va a actualizar $q ya que se realizo antes y ya esta en memoria.

me explico?

Comment: Gracias si, disculpa mi poco nivel, como lo puedo recuperar las variables, seria mejor recuperarla por medio de mysqli_fetch_object?